# How to build Silverlight 4 applications without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

We're setting up a TeamCity build server for continuous integration. To keep things clean, we don't want to install Visual Studio on the build server. I'm wondering how we can build Silverlight 4 apps without it?

I'd expect there to be a Silverlight 4 SDK which installs separately from VS - but so far I haven't found one. There's the Silverlight 4 tools for VS 2010, but that refuses to install without VS. I also found a link to a Silverlight 4 SDK RC, but I assume there should be an RTM version by now :).

If we have to, we can manually copy a few files from a VS machine to the build server. But we  don't want to do a full VS install, since it will make the CI environment too different from production.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visit the   [Silverlight Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838244(VS.95).aspx) topic on MSDN, scroll down to toward the bottom you will find a section on the Silverlight 4 SDK which includes a link to an independent install for the [SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169403) alone.  This install should not require VS and is what you need for a CI machine.